# Manipulating pointers using C

Tags: c, memory, pointers, allocation

While working with pointers in C, I have been experiencing a very incosistent result, I am working with a token which is a byte string which i need to make a directory path.
a token consists of the date as a prefix in the format of 20101129(2010-oct-29) and then a 20byte string follows, thus a token would look like 20101102A2D8B328CX9RDTBDE373, the method is supposed to return a path that looks like 2010/11/02/A2D8/B328/CX9R/DTBD/E373.

Now with the method that i used in the code provided below, returns strings which have unwanted characters while the code looks OK, the code is provided below

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define token "20101102A2D8B328CX9RDTBDE373"
#define SLASH "/"

int main()
{
    char *mainstring = (char*)malloc(strlen(token));
    char *nextstring = (char*)malloc(strlen(token));
    char tokenarr[50] = token;
    char patharr[50];
    char pathmem[50];
    char *fullstring = (char*)malloc(strlen(token));

    char yrstr[4]="";
    char yrmem[4]="";
    char yrarr[4]="";

    char monstr[2]="";
    char monmem[2]="";
    char monarr[2]="";

    char daystr[2]="";
    char daymem[2]="";
    char dayarr[2]="";

    memcpy(mainstring,token,strlen(token));


    memcpy(yrarr,tokenarr,4);
    strncpy(yrstr,mainstring,4);
    memcpy(yrmem,mainstring,4);

    puts(yrarr);
    puts(yrstr);
    puts(yrmem);


    mainstring = mainstring +4;
    memcpy(monarr,tokenarr+4,2);
    strncpy(monstr,mainstring,2); 
    memcpy(monmem,mainstring,2);

    puts(monarr);    
    puts(monstr); 
    puts(monmem);    

    mainstring = mainstring+2;
    memcpy(dayarr,tokenarr+6,2);
    strncpy(daystr,mainstring,2);
    memcpy(daymem, mainstring,2);

    puts(dayarr);
    puts(daystr);
    puts(daymem);

    strcat(patharr,yrarr); strcat(pathmem,yrmem);
    strcat(patharr,"/"); strcat(pathmem,SLASH);
    strcat(patharr,monarr);strcat(pathmem,monmem);
    strcat(patharr,"/"); strcat(pathmem,SLASH);
    strcat(patharr,dayarr); strcat(pathmem,daymem);

    puts(patharr);
    puts(pathmem);

    mainstring = mainstring +2;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        memcpy(nextstring,mainstring,4);
        mainstring = mainstring +4;
        printf("The %d th string is:",i+1);        
        puts(nextstring); strcat(fullstring,"/");
        strcat(fullstring, nextstring);

        puts(fullstring);
    }
    strcat(patharr,fullstring); 
    strcat(pathmem,fullstring);
    puts(patharr);
    puts(pathmem);


return 0;

}
```

The results from the code are:

2010
2010
2010
11
11m��
11
02m
02
02
2010/11/02m
��m�� 2010 /11/02
The 1 th string is:A2D8
/A2D8
The 2 th string is:B328
/A2D8/B328
The 3 th string is:CX9R
/A2D8/B328/CX9R
The 4 th string is:DTBD
/A2D8/B328/CX9R/DTBD
The 5 th string is:E373
/A2D8/B328/CX9R/DTBD/E373
2010/11/02m /A2D8/B328/CX9R/DTBD/E373
��m�� 2010 /11/02/A2D8/B328/CX9R/DTBD/E373

My main question is, why is it that the characters are included in the resulting strings? what i'm i doing wrong with the pointers?

Comment: It's very very bad style to have only one variable pointing to an address returned by malloc(), and then modify that variable. You should plan to call free() on the pointer and keep the original value stored unchanged for safety. Make a copy of the mainstring pointer in the beginning and then manipulate that.

Comment: Point of detail: 20101129 is 29 November 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are terminated by a null character (`'\0'`). Various strings you are using (such as `yrstr`) are not large enough to contain this null character, and you're not putting a null character into them.

For example, when you do this

```
strncpy(yrstr,mainstring,4);
```

no null character gets added to the string because `strncpy` omit the null character if there is not enough space in the destination string. You need to add the null character yourself, for example like this:

```
yrstr[4]='\0';
```

This requires `yrstr` to be large enough to contain at least five characters.

Comment: thank you for your response, will let you know of the updated changes

Comment: Note too that the arrays like `yrstr[4]` need to be `yrstr[5]` to allow for the trailing NULL.

Answer (score 7):

`strlen` returns the length of the string, not including the NULL terminator; therefore `memcpy` is not copying that, so the resulting string is not terminated.  The same applies with your `malloc`s.

You either need to use `strlen() + 1`, or use `strcpy()`.

Comment: Using strcpy() without allocating strlen()+1 invokes undefined behaviour - writing beyond the end of the allocated space.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to convert "20101102A2D8B328CX9RDTBDE373" into "2010/11/02/A2D8/B328/CX9R/DTBD/E373" then one way would be as follows;

```
// source string YYYYMMDD<20-char token>
char *src = "20101102A2D8B328CX9RDTBDE373";

// destination string, alloc space for source + 7 slashes + 1 null terminator
char *dest = (char *)calloc(1, strlen(src) + 7 + 1);

// now copy elements of src to dest, inserting intermediate slashes
<your code here>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your input, the results have now been consistent. would like to thank all that participated and contributed in helping me. I am posting code which includes all your input for the next learner to pick up from it. here goes:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define token "20101102A2D8B328CX9RDTBDE373"
#define SLASH "/"

int main()
{
    char *mainstring = (char*)malloc(strlen(token));
    char *nextstring = (char*)malloc(strlen(token));
    char tokenarr[50] = token;
    char patharr[50];
    char pathmem[50];
    char *fullstring = (char*)malloc(strlen(token));
    patharr[50]='\0';



    char yrstr[5];
    char monstr[3];    
    char daystr[3];

    yrstr[4] ='\0';
    monstr[2]='\0';
    daystr[2]='\0';



    memcpy(mainstring,token,strlen(token)+1);    
    strncpy(yrstr,mainstring,4);



    mainstring = mainstring +4;

    strncpy(monstr,mainstring,2); 


    mainstring = mainstring+2;    
    strncpy(daystr,mainstring,2);

    puts(yrstr);    
    puts(monstr); 
    puts(daystr);

    mainstring = mainstring +2;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        memcpy(nextstring,mainstring,4);
        mainstring = mainstring +4;
        printf("The %d th string is:",i+1);        
        puts(nextstring);strcat(fullstring,SLASH);
        strcat(fullstring, nextstring);

        puts(fullstring);
    }

return 0;

}
```

The result is:

```
2010
11
02
The 1 th string is:A2D8
2010/11/02/A2D8
The 2 th string is:B328
2010/11/02/A2D8/B328
The 3 th string is:CX9R
2010/11/02/A2D8/B328/CX9R
The 4 th string is:DTBD
2010/11/02/A2D8/B328/CX9R/DTBD
The 5 th string is:E373
2010/11/02/A2D8/B328/CX9R/DTBD/E373
```

Comment: Although this code might appear to run correctly, there are bugs in it.

For example in line 11, you've allocated strlen(token) bytes for mainstring but later, in line 31, you copy strlen(token) + 1 bytes from token into mainstring.

Comment: Quick follow-up: I compiled and ran this code and the bugs do have an impact.  The results of running the code are not correct and do not match what you see.

Comment: Thanks for having the eye for detail.